# "Hippo CMS" in my "Eclipse Luna", Tomcat not starting

Tags: tomcat8, eclipse-luna, hippocms

I am trying to integrate "`Hippo CMS`" in my "`Eclipse Luna`". For that i installed "`Tomcat 8`". But when i am trying to run the tomcat after adding the module to it. It is throwing error

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger".

I searched over google, it gives a solution, "That I either did not copy the shared folder correctly, or I did not copy the `conf/catalina.properties correctly`". But what need to be done, to resolve this issue and start my server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working locally then you can start your server with the mvn profile 'cargo.run'. This will automatically deploy a tomcat version.

If you need a standalone tomcat then perhaps this page will help you:
http://www.onehippo.org/library/development/create-a-project-distribution.html